# Breaking up a class with many methods for readability

Tags: java, processing

My grid super class has become large with many public methods and I'm trying to figure out how I can break it up to become more manageable. Methods fall into a few categories, methods below are for getting index info:

```
class grid{
 int tot, cols, rows;
 float gw, gh, w, h,gx,gy,gcx,gcy;
 ArrayList<cell> cells = new ArrayList<cell>();  

 grid(float width, float height, int cols, int rows){
   this.gx = 0;
   this.gy = 0;
   this.gw = width;
   this.gh = height;
   this.cols = cols;
   this.rows = rows;
   w = gw/float(cols);
   h = gh/float(rows);
 }

 // how to move these methods somewhere else?

 int rc(int row, int col){    // get index at row# col#
   int val = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++){
     if(cells.get(i).row == row && cells.get(i).col == col){
       val = i;
     }
   }
   return val;
 }

 int col(int inst){
   if(altFlow == 1){ 
     return floor(inst/rows);
   } else { 
     return inst%cols;
   }
 }

 int[] listRow(int indexIn){
   int stIndex = cols*indexIn;
   int[] arrayOut = new int[cols];
   for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++) arrayOut[i] = i+stIndex;
   return arrayOut;
 }
}
```

My thought was to use composition, but I would still need a method for each function in the main class? Is this the best way?

```
class grid{
  gridInfo gi;

  ...

  //still need one of these for each method?
  int col(int inst){
    return gi.col(inst);
  }
}

class gridInfo(){
  grid parent;
  ...

  int col(int inst){
    if(altFlow == 1){ 
      return floor(inst/parent.rows);
    } else { 
      return inst%parent.cols;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an abstract class defining some methods and then enhance it (derive from it) by adding more methods.

This tutorial explains abstract classes: https://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java

But I would not do that unless you have different classes derived from the same abstract base. I see no problem having large source code files. Every IDE provides lots of features to navigate quickly, regardless if the class has 100 or 3000 lines.